# When two voters meet, they switch allegiance; might they all ally with the same candidate?

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

> Let's assume that there are three candidates running in an election.
>   Right before the elections (when there is no more propaganda), it is
>   forbidden to gather in groups of more than two people to discuss the
>   candidates regarding the election.
>
> There are basically three groups of people: group *a* which would vote
>   for candidate A, group *b* which would vote for candidate B, and group *c*
>   which would vote for candidate C, in such a way that the following is
>   true: 0 < |*a*| < |*b*| < |*c*| (If we assume that the groups are sets).
>   Each time two people from different groups meet, they change their
>   opinions and vote for the third candidate. (So if a person which would
>   vote for A meets a person which would vote for B, then after their
>   conversation, they both would vote for C).
>
> The question is: can all of the voters (the union of groups *a*, *b*,
>   *c*) be persuaded to vote for the same candidate?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this problem is treated in Terence Tao's book *Solving Mathematical Problems: A Personal Perspective*, in the guise of a problem about colored chips, where you can remove two different-colored chips and replace them with two chips of the third color. I don't have my copy handy but perhaps that will help you or someone else.

Comment: [This math.SE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/145725/264) phrases it in terms of a riddle about chameleons who change color.

Comment: In case anyone needs this in the future, it's on page 83 of the Tao book, and an extensive discussion follows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $s_0 = \newcommand{\tuple}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}\tuple{a_0,b_0,c_0}$ be the initial state and $(s_k)_k$ be any sequence of following states. Set $$f(\tuple{a,b,c}) = \tuple{a-b, b-c, c-a} \bmod 3,$$ then $f(s_k) = f(s_0)$ for any $k$.

*Proof.*

Without loss of generality we can assume that

$$s_k = \tuple{a, b, c} \leadsto \tuple{a-1, b-1, c+2} = s_{k+1}.$$

Then:

\begin{align}
(a-1)-(b-1) &= a-b &&= a-b \pmod 3, \\
(b-1)-(c+2) &= b-c-3 &&= b-c \pmod 3, \\
(c+2)-(a-1) &= c-a+3 &&= c-a \pmod 3,
\end{align}

hence, $f(s_k) = f(s_{k+1})$.

Concluding, it is possible to get $a = b = 0$ only if $a_0-b_0 = 0 \pmod 3$. Moreover, there is a winning strategy if there are at least two different voters: WLOG we have $a \leq b$ (otherwise switch $a$ and $b$). First we obtain $c \geq b$ (trivial). Next we generate:
$\tuple{0, b_0-a_0, c_0+2a_0}$, then $\tuple{2\frac{b_0-a_0}{3},2\frac{b_0-a_0}{3}, c_0+2a_0-1\frac{b_0-a_0}{3}}$, and finally $\tuple{0, 0, a_0+b_0+c_0}$.

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: Crap, I've just went to make tea, and when I'm back there are 3 more posted answers similar to mine :-(

Answer (score 1):

No. Let group a have 1 person, group b have 2, and group c have 3. It's not difficult to go through the different possible meetings of people from the groups to see that (1,2,3) (0,2,4) and (0,1,5) are the only possible distributions of votes (up to permutations of the groups.)

Comment: I tried that, and I got a similar result. So, if the question was "is the persuasion possible in all the cases", your answer is full-n-final. But, that question omits the word "always", so I think we must provide in what cases it is possible, and in what cases it isn't. Even if the question was just asking about the always-possibility, still, it'd be interesting to find out where such a persuasion is possible or not!

Comment: I thought the word 'always' was implied. However, I can see how understanding the different cases would be more interesting.

Comment: No, 'always' is not implied. The question is about whether even one possibility exists. Feel free to edit it if you feel appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done whenever b-a is a multiple of 3,when c-a is a multiple of 3 and a+b is greater than or equal to c, and when c-b is a multiple of 3 and a+b is greater than or equal to c.  (3,6,7),(5,5,6),...(0,0,16). (5,6,9),(4,8,8),...(20,0,0) are examples.

Answer (score 0):

If $2*$|*a*|+ |*b*| = |*c*| - |*a*|, then there is a solution by having everyone in a meet someone from c in an initial round and then pair up b and c in the second round so that then everyone is for a as there isn't anything mentioned for how many conversations could happen.

If one needs an example for the above, consider if $a=1, b=2, c=5$.  Then after a and c meet, the values are $a=0,b=4,c=4$ and then each of b and c meet to produce the result of $a=8,b=0,c=0$.

The key is to get 2 of the 3 sets to have the same cardinality as then it is easy to move each of those people into the third set.

Answer (score 0):

It may also worth noting that for there to be an initial configuration $(a,b,c)$ where no two of $a$, $b$, $c$ are congruent mod $3$ (and therefore, as others have shown, it is impossible to reach unanimity), it is necessary and sufficient that
$a+b+c$ be divisible by $3$.